# Strange SyncServices / iSync console messages when saving ABAddressBook

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, abaddressbook, abperson

I'm displaying and editing an ABPerson with an ABPersonView. I do this like so:

```
ABPerson *person = (ABPerson *)[_addressBook recordForUniqueId:[curDict valueForKey:@"id"]];
[_personView setPerson:person];
[_personView setEditing:YES];
```

Where _personView is my ABPersonView. When I edit the ABPerson with the ABPersonView and I save the AddressBook:

```
[ABAddressBook addressBook] save];
```

It does save and in the AddressBook application I can see its value has changed, but I get these error messages in Xcode and Console:

I first get this:

```
sandboxd: ([3082]) AddressBookSync(3082) deny file-read-data /Users/xcodeuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CompanyName-asdxadsafadfqmwqxaagdsfgafguge/Build/Products/Debug
```

Followed by a lot of this:

```
sandboxd: ([3035]) AddressBookSync(3035) deny mach-lookup com.apple.syncservices.SyncServer
```

And it ends with this:

```
AddressBookSync[3035:707] [0x10011ba50] |ISyncManager|Warning| SyncServer is unavailable: timed out trying to connect
AddressBookSync[3035:707] AddressBookSync (client id: com.apple.AddressBook) error: Exception running AddressBookSync: Timed out waiting for the sync server
AddressBookSync exited with 2
```

My application is sandboxed and I integrated iCloud.

I have searched but could not find anyone having the same kind of problems, I have tried this:

- Using `[[ABAddressBook] sharedAddressBook]` instead of `[[ABAddressBook] addressBook]` but I then get an error from the ABPersonView saying the use of sharedAddressBook is deprecated with the ABPersonView.
- I added SyncServices framework, didn't help

The code does work though, at least with my iCloud account. Anyone got a clue to why I'm getting these errors? Is it worth a shot trying it with Xcode 4.3 and 10.8? I'm currently running 4.2.1 with Lion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen exactly this same problem. I believe you are seeing a bug in the Apple frameework.